# How to translate enums at angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I am trying to translate the enums at the Angular but the problem it is that I don't know how to translate them.
I can read them, I can show in a dropdown but not to translate.

Below is my code

```
export enum test {
 test1 = '1 - do something',
 test2 = '2 - do anything',
}
```

I read the data something like this

```
public getEnum: any = {};

public ngOnInit(): void {
Object.values(test).map(a: string) => {

const id = a.substr(0, 5);
this.getEnum[id] = a;
}
```

And in the html I have something like this

```
 [options]="getEnum"
```

The translate is something like this.

```
"dropdown": {
  "doSomething": {
    "test1": "1 - do something"
   }
}
```

Comment: From your code i got `{'1 - d': "1 - do something", '2 - d': "2 - do anything"}` in `getEnum`

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak You are right but same I get but the problem is how to translate for example: `1 - do something` ' is `en.json` but `1 - macht etwas` is `de.json`.
How to get the translations ?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak What do you suggest me to do so I can translate the `enums` ?

Comment: You should take a look at http://www.ngx-translate.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest little bit different approach. Do not translate it: keep in enum keys to translation.json file e.g.

```js
export enum Test {
 test1 = 'dropdown.doSomething.test1',
 test2 = 'dropdown.doSomething.test2',
}
```

I that case enum will not depend on current language and you will be able to easily translate value from enum by:

```js
const enTranslations = {
  dropdown: {
    doSomething: {
     test1: "1 - do something"
    }
  }
};

const getTranslatedText = (tranlations, keys: string[]) => keys.reduce((acc, curr) => acc[curr], translations);

const key1 = Test.test1
const translatedEnText = getTranslatedText(enTranslations, key1.split('.'));
```

Then you can display `translatedEnText`, or pass it into function call. `translatedEnText === '1 - do something'`

If you want to have text from the same key in different language just call `getTranslatedText` with other translation object e.g. `deTranslations`

If you want to map your enum into object with same keys and translated values do something like this:

```js
const testEng = Object.values(Test).reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: getTranslatedText(enTranslations, key.split('.'))}), {})
```

reducde will start with `{}` in `acc` and on each iteration step it will add to acc translated text from `getTranslatedText(enTranslations, key.split('.'))` (as value) under `key` key.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aenum%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20test1%20%3D%20'dropdown.doSomething.test1'%2C%0D%0A%20test2%20%3D%20'dropdown.doSomething.test2'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20enTranslations%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dropdown%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20test1%3A%20%221%20-%20do%20something%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20getTranslatedText%20%3D%20(tranlations%2C%20keys%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20keys.reduce((acc%2C%20curr)%20%3D%3E%20acc%5Bcurr%5D%2C%20tranlations)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20key1%20%3D%20Test.test1%0D%0Aconst%20translatedText%20%3D%20getTranslatedText(enTranslations%2C%20key1.split('.'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testEng%20%3D%20Object.values(Test).reduce((acc%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20...acc%2C%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20getTranslatedText(enTranslations%2C%20key.split('.'))%7D)%2C%20%7B%7D))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190407/discussion-on-answer-by-przemyslaw-pietrzak-how-to-translate-enums-at-angular-6). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to reflect any insights gained from the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a pipe that implements the translate service.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translateEnum'
})
export class TranslateEnumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  transform(value: string, enumName: string): string {
    return this.translate.instant(`ENUMS.${enumName}.${value}`); // this has to match your en.json file
  }
}
```

And then you can use it with type = "A"

```
<p>{{ type | translateEnum : 'TYPE' }}</p>
// this will return the value associated with the key 'ENUMS.TYPE.A'
```